Visual Basic Linq with Eager Loading Include
I want to start a Linq query with Visual Basic.
The query includes Eager Loading with Filtered Includes.
Customers should be invited who have at least one order.
Furthermore, I would like to limit the number of fields with Select.
So far I have tried the following:
Dim _List = Await (From _View In ctx.Customers.Where(Function(x) x.Customers_id.Equals(1000)) _
                  .Include(Function(z) z.Orders.Where(Function(i) i.Order_Price > 1000) _
                  .Select(Function(t) t.Order_Price)).ToListAsync

With the Select clause I want to display both Customersfields and Orderfields.
Unfortunately I get an error message, the command is not correct.
What am I doing wrong?
Dirk

What is the error that you get?

Start from removing Select.

Yes, you are right.
If I don't use the Select clause, I don't get an error message.
The problem then is that the data is not displayed to me in the form.
I would also like to limit the fields because of performance.

When you use Select, includes are ignored. Post your desired DTO class. I'm not sure that I can write right LINQ in VB, but in C# definetly.

My customer table contains 40 fields, if I need to load them all, isn't it better to use join with a select clause?

With EF Core, you almost do not need joins, everything can be expressed via navigation properties. In Select you can use navigation properties.

Thanks for the hint. Can you show me an example?
